# Connection Oriented Channel for L2CAP

Tags: bluetooth-le

Does Android support Connection oriented Channel for L2CAP in BLE?
What about in Android M ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from Texas Instruments can be found [here](http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/538/p/457797/1651834)

> neither of the major smart device OS's support L2CAP CO channels

meaning iOS and Android. posted Oct 7, 2015, after the launch of Marshmallow.

Comment: Looks like BlueZ has the support  -  in Bluez 5.x. I will update on this in sometime after checking more.

Comment: but BlueZ isn't used in Android...

Comment: Exactly, Agreed. But I was commenting to the above comment : "neither of the major smart device OS's support L2CAP CO channels".

Comment: Yes will be interesting to see how it develops for use on Ubuntu, raspian, etc